# I need to design the sprinkle chart but without using CorePlot.

Tags: ios

I need to design the chart which shows in below URL
http://screencast.com/t/paJruvguQ
But I have to achieve this goal without using CorePlot library , have to write the code from start.
Is there any solution how should I start this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recently i have developed a library for such purpose, you can download [here](https://github.com/DipenPanchasara/ChartView). make required modification to suit your requirement. Good luck